# A command to create, row and column of a matrix automatically

Tags: macros, matrices

I want to have a command its name `\RC`(row-column) that when I use \RC{5}{6} (for example), it make the below output:
[image]
The matrix elements are defined in the following example.

My minimal file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\ndef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname} 
\def\usageb#1{\csname #1\endcsname}
\ndef{a11}{1}
\ndef{a22}{2}
\ndef{a33}{6}
\ndef{a44}{5}
\ndef{a55}{8}
%Define \RC
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\usageb{a11}&~&~&~&~&~\\
~&\usageb{a22}&~&~&~&~\\
~&~&\usageb{a33}&~&~&~\\
~&~&~&\usageb{a44}&~&~\\
~&~&~&~&\usageb{a55}&~
\end{bmatrix}
\]
Now I want to \verb|\RC{5}{6}| make the above structure.
%\RC{5}{6}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are the inputs to `\RC` related to the output?

Comment: @Werner If I'm seeing it right, the inputs are the numbers of rows and columns in the output.

Comment: Okay, so to be more explicit: You first define a bunch of `\a<row><col>` macros, like `\a12`, `\a52`, ... and then `\RC{<rows>}{<cols>}` will create a matrix with that specific number of `<rows>` and `<columns>`, placing each `\a<row><col>` in the appropriate position (`<row>`, `<col>`). Is that interpretation correct?

Comment: ...the assumption is you will have less than 10 rows *and* columns, always.

Comment: @werner Thanks. your interpretation  is correct.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% Use a special prefix for the stored entries so we are less likely to overwrite any 
% other commands (not that it's very likely there is an existing macro called "\a11"...)
\newcommand\setmatrixentry[1]{\expandafter\def\csname matrixentry@@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\usematrixentry[3]{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname matrixentry@@#1#2#3\endcsname\relax\else
        \csname matrixentry@@#1#2#3\endcsname
    \fi
}
% #1 -- name of matrix
% #2 -- number of rows
% #3 -- number of columns
% We accumulate the matrix we are building in temporary variables 
% "\tempmatrix" and "\temprow". Use pgf "\foreach" for iteration.
\newcommand\printmatrix[3]{%
    \gdef\tempmatrix{}%
    \foreach\y in {1,...,#2}{%
        \gdef\temprow{}%
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#3} {%
            \xdef\temprow{%
                \unexpanded\expandafter{\temprow}%
                \ifnum\x=1\relax\else&\fi % Only add an "&" if this isn't the first entry
                \usematrixentry{#1}{\y}{\x}%
            }%
        }%
        \xdef\tempmatrix{%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\tempmatrix}%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\temprow}%
            \noexpand\\
        }%
    }%
    \begin{bmatrix}%
    \tempmatrix
    \end{bmatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

\setmatrixentry{a11}{1}
\setmatrixentry{a22}{2}
\setmatrixentry{a33}{6}
\setmatrixentry{a44}{5}
\setmatrixentry{a55}{8}

\[\printmatrix{a}{5}{5}\]

\[\printmatrix{a}{5}{6}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is so perfect.  Dear Hood Chatham, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a handier syntax with `expl3`.

The command `\definematrix` takes as arguments a symbolic name and a list of entries in the form `{ij}{x}` (1 ≤ i ≤ 9, 1 ≤ j ≤ 9). The input order is irrelevant.

The command `\printmatrix` takes as arguments a symbolic name (previously defined), the number of rows and the number of columns to print. Undefined entries will print a blank.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definematrix}{mm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name
  % #2 = list of entries
  \madadpour_matrix_def:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmatrix}{mmm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name
  % #2 = rows
  % #3 = columns
  \madadpour_matrix_print:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__madadpour_matrix_body_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { nv }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \madadpour_matrix_def:nn
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { l__madadpour_matrix_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn { l__madadpour_matrix_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \madadpour_matrix_print:nnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__madadpour_matrix_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nn { #3 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__madadpour_matrix_body_tl
       {
        % don't add & before the first entry
        \int_compare:nF { ####1 = 1 } { & }
        \str_case:nvF { ##1 ####1 } { l__madadpour_matrix_#1_tl } { \madadpour_matrix_empty: }
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__madadpour_matrix_body_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \tl_use:N \l__madadpour_matrix_body_tl
  \end{bmatrix}       
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \madadpour_matrix_empty: { \phantom{0} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definematrix{a}{
  {11}{1}
  {22}{2}
  {33}{6}
  {44}{5}
  {55}{8}
}

\definematrix{b}{
  {11}{-1}
  {12}{3}
  {21}{2}
  {22}{4}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\printmatrix{a}{5}{6} \qquad \printmatrix{b}{2}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

**Implementation.** The `\definematrix` command just populates a token list variable. With `\printmatrix` we populate a new token list variable by launching two nested loops: first a loop on the rows, with inside a loop on the columns; for each position (i,j), we look up whether an entry has been set and use it, otherwise print a blank (`\phantom{0}`). In the meantime `&` separators between cells are added and `\\` at the end of a row.

Finally, the built token list is output inside a `bmatrix` environment.

[image]

Comment: This is so excellent too. Thanks a lot dear egreg.